# Will referencing a website image on a local network compromise network security?

Tags: security, networking

I manage a website for an organization that has a network where several hundred users will access it in any given 15 minute period.  When a user opens a browser, the organization's homepage is displayed.  This homepage has several images on it.  To try to save on bandwidth to the remote web server (which is not at all affiliated with the local network), the index file checks the ip address of the requester and if it is coming from within the network, it displays a modified webpage where the images are pulled from a local shared drive on the network.

Essentially, the code is this:

```
<image src="file:\\\D:/hp/picture.jpg" />
```

I've been told by the network administrator that this is unacceptable because of the great security risk it poses and that the folder must be deleted immediately.

I'm pretty sure it's not a risk because it's the browser that requests the file from the local network and not the remote server and the only way the picture could be displayed is if the request came from the local network which all users have access to the drive in question anyway.

Is there something I am overlooking here?  Can this single image tag cause a "great security risk" to the network?

Some background to prevent the obvious questions that will arise from this:

1. Browser caches are cleared every time a new user logs on to a machine.  New users log in roughly every 15 minutes on over 500 machines.
2. I've requested to have a proxy cache server set up globally for the network.  The network administrators flat out refused to do this
3. Hosting from within the network is out of the question (again, by the decree of the network administrator)
4. I have no control over the network or have any part in the decisions that are made.
5. Every user has read access to this shared drive and they all have write access to at least some of the 100 or so directories within it.
6. The network is not remotely accessible by remote users (you must be logged in to a machine physically plugged into the network to access the network or any drive on it)

Thanks in advance for your help on this.

Comment: This must be one big image :]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use the very same server which serves the shared directory to share the images over HTTP, and just use:

```
<image src="http://local-server/images/hp/picture.jpg" />
```

You already have a server, it's a matter of using the proper software.

Regarding another of your points, it **might** be dangerous.  You're allowing your browser to access local files requested by remote websites.  I can't think of any exploits of the top of my head, but I'd rather avoid this sort of uncommon practice.  You should not do something until you're sure it's safe (for now you're just unsure it's unsafe).

Comment: Thank you, Hugo, for your prompt response.

I think what you are suggesting is for the local server to be set up to serve http requests, correct?  Unfortunately, the network admins will not allow this.

Comment: By the way, any user on the local network can enter file:\\\D:/hp/pciture.jpg in their browser address bar and access to that image as well as any other file on the drive.

Comment: One other thought:  couldn't anyone create a webpage with a similar local file request?  It seems to me a network security issue that allows any webpage to access local files would be dangerous.

Comment: I remember creating a webpage that references a local image, and Opera prompted about a secutriy warning before showing the image.  I just tried this with firefox, and it refuses to show the image if the page is hosted remotely. I'm sure the users have configured their browser at some point to allow this (either them, or whoever set up their computers).
The default for both opera and firefox is to warn or not show the image at all. Not sure about other browsers.

Comment: Yes, I am aware that most modern browsers will not open a local image file unless the browser is configured to trust certain content. However on this particular network, the users only have access to IE8, which happily opens anything you ask :-)

Answer (score 0):

Is the tag itself a "great security risk"?  Of course not -- any site can do the same (as you said, IE8 "happily opens everything you ask").  And therein lies the risk: *should* any website to be allowed to coerce the client into opening arbitrary network files?

From a security standpoint, the problem is likely not the image tag itself, but rather that this functionality requires that Internet sites be allowed to coerce access local resources (over the file: protocol) in the client's security context.  Even with same-origin policy, this is potentially dangerous, and consequently modern browsers do not allow it.

Beginning with IE9, Microsoft disallows accessing the file: protocol from sites in the Internet zone, and "[strongly discourages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330731%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#file_protocol_nav)" disabling this feature.  Other modern browsers have similar functionality.

Presumably, the network administrators will eventually need to upgrade from IE8.  Upgrading to a newer browser will prevent, by default, the locally-accessed images from loading.  So the organization then ultimately has a few choices:

1. Turn off this security setting, allowing any website to reference local content
2. Not upgrade, and use IE8 in perpetuity
3. Run the website in the "Trusted Zone", which by default will permit the site to do anything the user can do (start processes, delete files, read data, etc.).
4. Develop custom software (BHOs, custom applications, HTAs, etc.) or use COTS software to load the images locally, bypassing the default IE behavior.
5. Accept the usability impact associated with not showing the local images

Option (1) is clearly a security issue, since it requires disabling a security setting that prevents non-local websites from reading local content.  Option (2) presents it own security issues, since older browsers lack some of the security features of newer browsers (like blocking file: protocol access from the Internet zone).  Option (3) requires an administrative configuration change, violates least access principles, and (particularly if the site lacks server verification (SSL)) opens the organization to a new and potentially-devastating attack vector.

That leaves Option 4 -- development/deployment of software for this purpose; and Option 5 -- block the images from being displayed.

In the end, the administrators will likely have a strong security interest in moving away from IE8, and an implementation that uses a behavior new browsers do not support can impede such an upgrade, and could reasonably contradict the security interests of the organization.